# Java - How to check if all positions in an array have the same value?

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following do while:

```
do{    
     (...)
}while(cont_pares[0]!=2 || cont_pares[1]!=2 || cont_pares[2]!=2 || cont_pares[3]!=2 || cont_pares[4]!=2 || cont_pares[5]!=2 || cont_pares[6]!=2 || cont_pares[7]!=2 || cont_pares[8]!=2);
```

Is there any other way to check if there is a position in the array that doesn't have the value 2?

Comment: Write a method: `arrayContains(int[] arr, int value)` which loops over the array.

Comment: `while (Arrays.stream(cont_pares).anyMatch(x -> x != 2));` ? (what do you want to do when at least one is not 2?) - I'm confused.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch. If at least one is not 2 it returns to the begining of the cicle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `cont_pares` is an `int[]`, use `IntStream`:

```
while (IntStream.of(cont_pares).noneMatch(a -> a == 2))
while (IntStream.of(cont_pares).allMatch(a -> a != 2))
```

If it's an `Integer[]`, use `Stream<Integer>`:

```
while (Stream.of(cont_pares).noneMatch(a -> a == 2))
while (Stream.of(cont_pares).allMatch(a -> a != 2))
```

or

```
while (!Arrays.asList(cont_pares).contains(2));
```

Comment: It pretty much has to be one of these. Nice. I got confused as to which terminating behavior OP wanted. Double negatives are not second to none when it comes to speaking in English.

Comment: Thanks for the help, using IntStream.of(cont_pares).anyMatch(a -> a != 2) solved my problem

Comment: @demolion that's not what you asked in the question: you show a loop which will execute until all of its elements are two. The code in this comment will execute until any one of the elements is *not* 2.

Comment: @AndyTurner Good! I'm not the only one [confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410315/java-how-to-check-if-all-positions-in-an-array-have-the-same-value/61410391#comment108634993_61410315).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList` rather than the array and check that it does not have value

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
do{    
     (...)
}while(!list.contains(Integer.valueOf(2)));
```